# Navigation Bar change color when running

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

When I switch to another screen, the navigation bar (white) turns gray (if I put another color took a darker shade of the same color)

This is my code to choose the color

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

Any idea to prevent this from happening and keep the color I want

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try below, it will surely works.**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false;

self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
```

while going to other screen your navigation bar turns gray because, On iOS7 and later, `translucent` property of `UINavigationBar` is true by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1)

```
var controller= UINavigationController(rootViewController:YourViewController)    
controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

2)

```
 var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
 navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
 navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: there is no need to set property for navigationbar object as well as using appearence proxy with same value, by the way this not solve the issue of @Jose Saracho